# Non-recursive algorithm to walk the edges of a Voronoi diagram with boost::polygon

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, voronoi, boost-polygon

What's a good algorithm to traverse the edges of a Voronoi diagram using boost without recursion?

I know it'd have to check for infinite edges in a cell then check its neighbours and repeat from there, but I'd prefer a method that doesn't require recursion since I'm dealing with large sets of data.

Is this possible without recursion?

**Edit, for more clarification:**

This is a way to obtain all edge cells:

```
voronoi_diagram vd;
boost::polygon::construct_voronoi(in.begin(), in.end(), &vd);

std::vector<const voronoi_diagram::cell_type *> edge_cells;

for(const voronoi_diagram::edge_type & e : vd.edges())
  if (e.is_infinite())
    edge_cells.push_back(e.cell());
```

The problem with the approach above is that it will not traverse the edge cells in any specific order, say clockwise for example.

A **recursive** implementation would do something akin to this (hastily written and untested) code:

```
bool findNext(const voronoi_diagram::cell_type * c,
              std::list<const voronoi_diagram::cell_type *> & list)
{
  const voronoi_diagram::edge_type * e = c->incident_edge();
  do
  {
    // Follow infinite edges, adding cells encountered along the way
    if (e->is_infinite() && e->twin()->cell() != list.front() &&
      e->twin()->cell() != list.back())
    {
      list.push_back(c);
      return findNext(e->twin()->cell(), list);
    }
    else if (e->twin()->cell() == list.front())
    {
      list.push_back(c);
      return true; // we reached the starting point, return
    }      
    e = e->next();
  } while (e != c->incident_edge());
  return false;
}
// ...
std::list<const voronoi_diagram::cell_type *> edge_cells;
// ...
for(const voronoi_diagram::edge_type & e : vd.edges())
{
  // find first infinite edge
  if (e.is_infinite())
  {
    if (findNext(e.cell(), edge_cells))
      break;
    else
      edge_cells.clear();
  }
}
```

This would traverse the edges of the Voronoi diagram until it traces its way back to the first cell and then stops, filling the stack all the way.

A non-recursive implementation would model the second example, producing a list of the edge cells in a clockwise or counter-clockwise order, without using recursion.

Comment: Have you tried using iteration in a loop instead of recursion?

Comment: Yes, nested loops, and it gets so complicated it's almost not viable compared to a recursive method. That's why I'd like to see a fresh perspective on the subject, maybe I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: @voodooattack:If u read my answer I wrote clearly it's about convex hull. Maybe u can share an image of the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have one recursive call in `findNext` and it is `return findNext(...)` so the so-called [tail-call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) optimization can be applied. Your compiler might do it at -O3. But if you don't trust the compiler to do this, you can do it by hand. Below is the transformed function, no longer recursive:

```
bool findNext(const voronoi_diagram::cell_type * c, 
          std::list<voronoi_diagram::cell_type *> & list)
{
  const voronoi_diagram::edge_type * e = c->incident_edge();
  bool justCalled; // true when we repalce the tail call
  do
  {
    justCalled = false;
    // Follow infinite edges, adding cells encountered along the way
    if (e->is_infinite() && e->twin()->cell() != list.front() &&
        e->twin()->cell() != list.back())
    {
      list.push_back(c);
      c = e->twin()->cell();    // reassigns function argument
      e =  c->incident_edge();  // replay the initiaization (before do loop)
      justCalled = true;        // force the loop to continue
      continue;                 // jump to start of loop
      // everything happens as if we called findNext(e->twin()->cell(), list);
    else if (e->twin()->cell() == list.front())
    {
      list.push_back(c);
      return true; // we reached the starting point, return
    } 
    e = e->next();
  } while (justCalled || e != c->incident_edge());
  return false;
}
```

This function is equivalent to the one you wrote, so you'd use it the same and you're sure there's no recursion involved. The `bool` flag is necessary because `continue` jumps to the test of the loop and not its body [see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6e3dc2z3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), thus the test might fail before the loop even begins when we change arguments and call continue.

This is a general technique, not specific to graph traversal but to all recursive algorithms. Of course if you have many function arguments and a large body of code, the transform is heavy lifting, but in this case I think it's a good match.

In more complex cases when the recursion is not a tail call, you still can "de-recusify" any function by maintaining your own stack. This has the advantage that replacing the stack structure with say a priority fifo may change the traversal order in ways more subtle that what recursion can (easily) achieve.

Comment: I updated the code to match what you changed. I saw you added a push_back in the else if, the misbehavior probably came from there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41957/discussion-between-antoine-and-voodooattack)

Comment: Note: the original answer didn't work because `continue` runs the loop condition leading to premature exit. This is now fixed.

Comment: Man, SO is being slow with me giving out the bounty. But nice job in coming up with an answer :).

Comment: @Phpdna Sorting would probably help speed up the performance but voodooattack has already accepted the answer he wanted. Also I was doing the bounty because I thought this was an interesting question that was not getting enough attention. The downvote was not me btw :P

Comment: @Phpdna Boost doesn't allow you to sort the points before creating the diagram. I'm sorry but you don't seem to know what the question is about.